# Build and run Qt SQL plugin

Tags: sql, qt, db2, driver

I am trying to use the DB2 SQL support in Qt 5.

The latest Qt source was cloned from Git and built using the directions at
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html

The DB2 driver was built with the directions at
http://http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qdb2

This resulted in qslqdb2.dll and qsqldb2d.dll which I copied over to my installed QtCreator at
d:\qt-open\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\sqldrivers

But when I run d:\qt-open\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator and execute
m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QDB2");
it fails and reports
QSqlDatabase: QDB2 driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL

I would have run QtCreator from the source build I just did but there is no qtcreator.exe built.

Comment: When you build Qt, you don't build Qt Creator, it's a separate tool that you can build once you've built Qt.

Answer (score 2):

Qt Creator is just an IDE. Adding SQL plugins to Qt Creator's plugins folder is pointless, unless you want Qt Creator to use these plugins itself.

You need to add the plugins to your Qt's installation folder.

Comment: I have an application that I am running in Qt Creator and want to use the DB2 plugin that I built. Where do I put the DLLs? Isn't the Qt installation somewhere in my d:\qt-open installation?

Comment: A more basic question is can I build the DB2 SQL plugin and use it with an existing Qt/QtCreator installation or do I need to build everything from source including my plugin. I'm actually trying to add DB2 support to QGIS which uses Qt but am not having much success.

Comment: Forget about Qt Creator. It's like Eclipse or Visual Studio. It is not directly involved in this. My answer should be read as: **Completely ignore `d:\qt-open\Tools\QtCreator`.** You need a different folder. You say you built your own copy of Qt, just look in the installation directory, there should be a `bin\plugins` or `lib\plugins` folder there.

Comment: Let me simplify my questions:
1. Can I just build the DB2 SQL plugin without building all of Qt from source? 
2. Will the standard Qt installation recognize that the DB2 SQL support is available if the DLL is put in the right place in the Qt runtime directories?
3. I realize Qt Creator is an IDE but it is convenient to use for development. If I download and install Qt Creator, where does my DB2 SQL DLL go in order for it to be accessible?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. Nowhere. Qt Creator is a black box as far as Qt is concerned. It doesn't come with a copy of Qt for you to use. You must already have your own copy that you then let Creator know about. I really mean that you should forget about Creator. Look into your Qt install folder. What's so hard about that? I've already told you to do that. Why didn't you?? Why are you dragging it out? If you installed Qt, don't you know where you put it?